# Flexbox item's height collapsed on IE

Tags: css, flexbox

As you can see on the fiddle what i’m trying to achieve is that the image is centered in the block and the text is positioned to the bottom.

This works fine on chrome but on ie11 it looks like the height of the .item container has collapsed so the layout looks totally broken. Have I over complicated this or there a known IE bug with the way I have done this?

http://jsfiddle.net/kco6ybd4/7/ (Add show to the end of the url to view on IE11)

```
.row {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  width: calc(100% * (1/4));
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image {
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.text {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I sometimes see bugs with IE11 when a flex container is also a flex item but it happens occasionally in specific setups. I haven't been able to pin down the exact scenario to reproduce it. But you could try to avoid the above situation and see if it improves. Or you can just do the text and the image in 2 different rows to achieve the same look. Looking at the code again, I would just do a row of images center aligned, and a row of text.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very interesting, so I have tried different ways to find a possible cross browser solution. The big problem for me is to get the exact max-width for every image (this is possible with jquery or in php when you echo images, but I wanted to find a pure CSS solution 'cause this was the trick). To to this, I hardcore the code (I know, it is not so beautiful) with a single media-query that you can change with a better width.

This metod is cross-browser (I tested with IE11). Maybe it is not a correct solution for you, but I think it's a possible way to face the problem. :)

Try this:

```
.row {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  width: calc(100% * (1/4));
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 1px; /* trick for IE11 */
}

.image {
  flex: 1 1 auto;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 1px; /* trick for IE11 */
}

img {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.text {
  height: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```